# Wordpress feed and post titles duplicating

Tags: wordpress, feed, title

I just checked the feed title and some of the post titles also and is very much confused. The title is duplicating itself like: Site Title | Site Title. Here is the link of the feed:
http://www.dharamshalatravels.com/feed

Please let me know any solutions for this. I have checked the core files and there is no problems in those files.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I usually replace the core feeds:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds
I'll usually make a custom template and assign it to a page.
In the custom template I'll build my own RSS.

The title is made by: `<title><?php bloginfo_rss('name'); wp_title_rss(); ?></title>`
both these functions can be filtered.

with `add_filter('wp_title_rss','');`
and `add_filter('bloginfo_rss','');`

Some template or plugin is probably screwing this up.
add you own filters to find out which of the two (if not both?) is messing it up and apply your own filter.

Comment: thanks for the response mate...
post titles within the feed are fine but the feed title itself is duplicated...

Comment: you can also change the title with that custom template

Comment: The problem is not only with the feed titles, its also with some other post and category titles.
Have a look at the title <title>...</title> of this link :
http://www.dharamshalatravels.com/placecategory/hotels-in-dharamshala/

Comment: is the problem is due to some function as i checked by deactivating all the plugins but the problem is still there. what code should i check in functions.php file ?

Comment: first check your general settings tab, what is your site name and description there? Is that all right?

Comment: This is the site title : Hotels in Dharamshala, Car Rental Dharamshala, Holiday in Dharamshala | Dharamshala Travels


This is the description: We have a range of Hotels in Dharamshala. DharamshalaTravels.Com is one place to fulfill all your travel needs for an unforgettable Holiday in Dharamshala.

Comment: If that long string is your title then the categories is correct.you do know that google won't index such ling site titles: http://www.weseo.com.au/SEO-FAQ/META-Tags/What-is-the-maximum-page-title-length-for-the-Google-search-engine/

Comment: I know mate that google wont index long titles, but this is the title: Hotels in Dharamshala, Car Rental Dharamshala, Holiday in Dharamshala | Dharamshala Travels

Comment: that's your choice.. anyway the RSS feed title is wrong. Just apply your own filters to it

Comment: just give it low priority to make sure it is run last